# Organize generated Label in a page by column Javascript/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a little project which creates forms according to an array. The code is taking the value of the array choices[] to create checkboxes for each element of the array.

To make it nicer, I have a variable which set the number of element by row I'm expexting for "columnNumber" and an other one which counts how many column do I when the checkboxes are generated "ActualColumn". Everytime "actualColumn" becomes bigger than "columnNumber" I insert a 
 with document.createElement("br") by the NextLine() function.

But I dont succeed in reparting them in equal spaces for one to eache other.
for exemple if I whant 3 element by row. I would like to have one in the left side, one in the middle and right side.

Here is a snippet to let you see how it works for now I commented to guide you:

```js
//array of options
var choices = new Array();
choices[0] = "January";
choices[1] = "February";
choices[2] = "March";
choices[3] = "April";
choices[4] = "May";
choices[5] = "June";
choices[6] = "July";
choices[7] = "August";
choices[8] = "September";
choices[9] = "October";
choices[10] = "November";
choices[11] = "December";

//number of column
var columnNumber = 3;
var actualColumn = 0;
var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var val = '';
var cap = "";

var j = "";
var t = document.getElementById('t');

// the loop is creating the checkboxes with name, value...
for (var i in choices) {
  //increment the actualColumn to notice that we're adding an element
  actualColumn++;
  
  //If the number of element become bigger that the number of columns wanted we execute NextLign() and pass actualColumn to 1.
 if (actualColumn > columnNumber) {
  NextLign();
  actualColumn = 1;
 } else {
 }
 
  //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
  var nouvelleLigne = document.createElement("div");
  nouvelleLigne.innerHTML = "\n";
  j = i.toString();
  
  val = j;
  //cap will be the value/text of choices[i]
  var cb = document.createElement('input');
  var label = document.createElement("label");

  //initializing the checkboxes
  cap = choices[i];
  var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
  cb.type = 'checkbox';
  cbh.appendChild(cb);
  cb.name = cap;
  cb.value = val;
  label.appendChild(cb);
  label.appendChild(text);
  cbh.appendChild(label);
}
//insert a <br> to pass to the next row
function NextLign(){
 var br = document.createElement("br");
 var foo = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
 foo.appendChild(br);
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#data {
 padding:5px;
 width:100vw;
}
.multiselect {
 overflow: visible;
 padding:0;
 padding-left:1px;
 border:none;
 width:100vw;
 white-space: normal;
 height:75px;
 text-align: center;
}
.checkboxes {
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background-color:white;
 margin-left:-1px;
}
label {
 display: inline-flex;
 border: 1px grey solid;
 padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
 <div id="data">
  <div class="multiselect">
   <div id="c_b">
    <div id="checkboxes">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

If someone has an answer it would be nice to update the snippet to let me see how you did it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you right, but you want something like a table with 3 columns and fixed width for each column?

Comment: Somthing like a table yes, but the columns could be different with the value of the variable columnNumber. So the width of each column should be adaptable, but if your question concern the entier table so yes the table width would be fixed

Comment: @hallleron look in the snippet, if you change the value of column number you will change the organization of the checkboxes.

Comment: If you want something like a table with 3 columns and fixed width for each column, you could simply give `width: 20%;` property to **label** in your css. here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pupouhkm/)

Comment: @MrASquare Yes but I would like to render this table dynamic because the array of options will change, as the number of column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this part:

> For exemple if I whant 3 element by row. I would like to have one in the left side, one in the middle and right side.

I removed `text-align: center;` from  `.multiselect` and added one choice[12] = 'Jan'; if you add one more choice as choice[13]='Feb' it will come in the middle.

```js
//array of options
var choices = new Array();
choices[0] = "January";
choices[1] = "February";
choices[2] = "March";
choices[3] = "April";
choices[4] = "May";
choices[5] = "June";
choices[6] = "July";
choices[7] = "August";
choices[8] = "September";
choices[9] = "October";
choices[10] = "November";
choices[11] = "December";
choices[12] = "Jan";

//number of column
var columnNumber = 3;
var actualColumn = 0;
var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var val = '';
var cap = "";

var j = "";
var t = document.getElementById('t');

// the loop is creating the checkboxes with name, value...
for (var i in choices) {
  //increment the actualColumn to notice that we're adding an element
  actualColumn++;
  
  //If the number of element become bigger that the number of columns wanted we execute NextLign() and pass actualColumn to 1.
 if (actualColumn > columnNumber) {
  NextLign();
  actualColumn = 1;
 } else {
 }
 
  //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
  var nouvelleLigne = document.createElement("div");
  nouvelleLigne.innerHTML = "\n";
  j = i.toString();
  
  val = j;
  //cap will be the value/text of choices[i]
  var cb = document.createElement('input');
  var label = document.createElement("label");

  //initializing the checkboxes
  cap = choices[i];
  var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
  cb.type = 'checkbox';
  cbh.appendChild(cb);
  cb.name = cap;
  cb.value = val;
  label.appendChild(cb);
  label.appendChild(text);
  cbh.appendChild(label);
}
//insert a <br> to pass to the next row
function NextLign(){
 var br = document.createElement("br");
 var foo = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
 foo.appendChild(br);
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#data {
 padding:5px;
 width:100vw;
}
.multiselect {
 overflow: visible;
 padding:0;
 padding-left:1px;
 border:none;
 width:100vw;
 white-space: normal;
 height:75px;
}
.checkboxes {
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background-color:white;
 margin-left:-1px;
}
label {
 display: inline-flex;
 border: 1px grey solid;
 padding:5px;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<form>
 <div id="data">
  <div class="multiselect">
   <div id="c_b">
    <div id="checkboxes">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```